# Get weights in keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

when I'm trying to use `get_weights` to get weights of a layer of a CNN in keras it cause an error and said:
'Tensor' object has no attribute 'weights'.
I saw the keras documentation and it said use the `get_weights` command in order to work with weights.
so I don't know what is wrong with it.
I also using keras 2.2.4

here is a part of my code:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(32,32,3))
conv1 = Conv2D(32,(5,5), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_layer)
conv2 = Conv2D(32,(5,5), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
maxpool1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(conv2)
conv3 = Conv2D(32,(5,5), activation='relu', padding='same')(maxpool1)
conv4 = Conv2D(32,(5,5), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
maxpool2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(conv4)
conv5 = Conv2D(32,(5,5), activation='relu', padding='same')(maxpool2)
flatten1 = Flatten()(conv5)
dense1 = Dense(128, kernel_initializer='random_normal', bias_initializer='zeros')(flatten1)
dense2 = Dense(128,kernel_initializer='random_normal', bias_initializer='zeros')(dense1)
output_layer = Dense(10,activation='softmax',kernel_initializer='random_normal', bias_initializer='zeros')(dense2)
Cifar10_CNN = Model(input_layer, output_layer)

print(Cifar10_CNN.summary())

Cifar10_CNN.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), loss=categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])

conv1_weight_visualization = conv1.get_weights()
plt.imshow(conv1_weight_visualization)
```

Comment: We cannot know what is wrong either if you don't provide actual code, you are most likely calling get_weights in the wrong object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for layer in Cifar10_CNN.layers: 
   print(layer.name, np.array(layer.get_weights()))
```

You can obtain each layer weights like this.